# How do I stop java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout whilst using the ChatGPT API for my Android app?

Tags: java, android, openai-api, socket-timeout-exception

I have the issue where whenever I attempt to get a response from the [ChatGPT Java API by Theo Kanning](https://github.com/TheoKanning/openai-java), I get the error message `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout` after waiting ~10 seconds. I was wondering if there is a way to extend the limit, as all of the responses I've seen before regarding this error code mention `OkHttp` which I am not using, or editing `CONTEXT.XML` which I cannot find in my project files.

The code:

```
// [rest of function, does not include Socket class]
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      String response = queryGPT();
      System.out.println(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("There was an error: "+e);
    }
  }
});
thread.start();
```

```
queryGPT() {
  String query = myQuery;
  OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService(myKey);
  CompletionRequest request = CompletionRequest.builder()
    .prompt(myQuery)
    .model("text-davinci-003")
    .temperature(0.5)
    .maxTokens(1500)
    .frequencyPenalty(0.0)
    .presencePenalty(0.0)
    .bestOf(1)
    .echo(false)
    .build();
  List<CompletionChoice> response = service.createCompletion(request).getChoices();
  return response.get(0).getText();
}
```

Comment: As per TheoKanning openAi documentation you can pass timeout as OkHttpClient client = defaultClient(token, timeout) or   OpenAiService service = new OpenAiService(myKey, 30); //  The default value is 10 seconds, so you can set it to a higher value, such as 30 seconds

Comment: The SocketTimeOut is optional and is designed to close connections that don't have data transmission for a certain time. You can increase it to multiple minutes or simply disable it by setting it to 0.

Comment: Ask ChatGPT?   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to OpenAiService is the timeout specified as Duration. Here is 60 seconds.

```
OpenAiService api = new OpenAiService(OPENAI_API_KEY, Duration.ofSeconds(60));
```